# Passing file and data to requests, error at every turn

Tags: python, python-requests

Python 3.6.7, Requests 2.21.0

I have an issue that gives me a new error at every solution.

What I want: To send a file with data in a POST command using the requests library.

```
url_upload = BASE_URL + "upload?action=save"
data = {'data':{'name':'test.txt','contenttype':'text/plain', 'size':37}}
files = {'file': open('/home/user/test.txt', 'rb')}
req = session.post(url=url_upload, files=files, data=data)
```

The end server is using Spring (I assume) and the response text contains this error:

```
"net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with \'{\' at character 1 of name"
```

So, I try

```
data = json.dumps(data)
```

But, of course requests doesn't want that:

```
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

If I add the headers:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the data part, use `json` to pass a dictionary: `session.post(json=data)`

Comment: The server then gives me this error: "You must specify a non-empty data parameter"

Comment: It might work with `session.post(params=json.dumps(data))` but it's hard to know without the spec of the server

Comment: Same error, "You must specify a non-empty data parameter". It seems as if I'll need to find a way to post a string whether requests wants to or not... Thanks for the tips though :)

Comment: If all this doesn't work you can always try to build a valid curl request (by testing all options :) https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request ) and then translate back to python/requests

Comment: This does the conversion for you https://curl.trillworks.com/ :D

Comment: Oh wow... that's extremely useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to do was:

req = session.post(url=url_upload, files=files, data={'data': json.dumps(data)})

That way I'm giving the function variable 'data' the form-data variable name 'data' which contains the variable that has the key 'data'...

http://www.trekmate.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Data-star-trek-the-next-generation-31159191-1024-768.png